# Shadow sync bucket to main bucket

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have 1 sync gateway bucket(lets say sg_bucket) and anther main bucket(lets say mb_bucket). When I put data in mb_bucket I can see it in sg_bucket because I have done bucket shadowing. But when I retrieve a document on an app from sg_bucket and update it and then send back to sg_bucket I dont get an updated document on mb_bucket. Seems like bucket shadowing is working one way only ie from mb_bucket to sg_bucket but not the other way round. Is there any way I can make bucket shadowing work both ways

Comment: Hi, Bucket shadowing is not supported anymore by Couchbase and it's usage is discourage. The reco is to use Sync gateway's rest api.